# Executing a stored procedure using VB in Visual Studio 2013 return this error: "ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized."

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
enter code here
    Dim cs As String = "Data Source=RICH\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=dbTest;Integrated Security=True"
    Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.proc_RefreshData"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

This stored procedure is only used to update a SQL Server Table with new daily information, it doesn't return any results.

Comment: You forgot `cmd.Connection = con`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now, I'm new to this and spent hours searching for this simple statement. Very much appreciated.